# Increase margin-left by multipling to number in css

Tags: html, css, margin

i want to make hierarchy tree that uses margin left. And I want to multiply margin left to level of hierarchy in every level of hierarchy and make like tree. How to do that in css style? 
It is like Lpad('   ', 5*level), but i need it in css

Comment: Show a proof of concept with some code. We'll _help_ you with your code, not write it for you

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, your html tree elements are nested in each other. So just apply margin-left:

```
ul {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

And your html will be:

```
<ul> <!-- margin-left: 20px; -->
   <li>
       <ul> <!-- margin-left: 20px + 20px from parent = 40px -->
           <li>
               <ul> <!-- margin-left: 20px + 40px from previous `ul` elements -->
               ...
```

[JSFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/Justinas_Jurciukonis/t5REQ/)